# How much disk space do I need to install Fedora?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I want to  install Fedora 20 with GNOME 3. How much disk space do I need?

Comment: Depends on what else you will install. I have Debian I use a 20GB partition for root. I am currently using 8GB. Debian uses a lot of shared dependencies so as I install more it grows more slowly. Fedora may use more it is (enterprise) :-)

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/38675/fedora-20-how-much-space-needed-for-slash-root-partition/?answer=38716#post-id-38716

Comment: @richard I want install only JDK8 & NetBeans IDE 8 so if I use just 40 gb ,is it sufficient? Thank You

Comment: Probably: I have much more than java IDE installed, I have Java ×2 (android & not android), C#/mono, python, Eiffel, Scratch, Latex, network analysers, revision control ×4, Video players, drawing programs, other multimedia, games,  …

Comment: @richard Thank You friend , I get latest fedora 20 GNOME3 and now I need just 320 GB HDD I've ordered it  on saturday I will got. and I like human theme of linux and just a reason to use linux is jdk8 stop support to windows xp 32 bit so and I want kick ass xp if you don't mind I don't like .net framework and Microsoft product I love Java. I experience that so many students laugh in classroom at Java and I'm afraid that but I knew that they are using and having performance issue with .net framework, I'm beginner to use Linux. Sorry I write lot sorry and Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the Fedora web site](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Welcome_to_Fedora_.html#hardware_overview), you will need around 10 GB disk space during install. You will probably want more, though, if you are going to have large packages (like LaTeX, games, etc...). 20~30 GB won't hurt and should be enough for most users.

Comment: I was about to answer that... +1 . Most of my Fedora machines need to use 40/50Gb space to have all the stuff they needs.

Comment: @Wilf  I've 40 GB HDD is sufficient for Fedora 20 GNOME3

Comment: @user73898 - not enough for 3 versions of Blender (different plugins/interfaces), 2/3 Virtual Machines, Wine with varying Windows rubbish, web server, nearly every single FOSS graphical type program released in the past decade... - you don't *need* it, but it works well for most stuff all the same :)

Comment: @Wilf  please so which HDD I should use  320GB or 500 GB. I won't use it in virtual box I want realise Linux .  Thank You :-)

Comment: I don't use it *in* virtualbox, I use it to host 3 VirtualBox VMs... 320GB would be absolutely fine, you can get bigger drive if you like.

Answer (score 3):

I think minimum is 8-10 Gb, because there is lot of updates after installation.